# Rails 4 generates test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.2.3 with sqlite. I have a simple 'assert true' unit test, using the built in ActiveSupport::TestCase.

There is one migration in db/migrate.

I am not sure why the following causes tests to run successfully, I expect to get a 'pending migrations' error:

```
rwc $ rake db:drop:all
rwc $ rake db:migrate:status
Schema migrations table does not exist yet.
rwc $ rake db:migrate:status RAILS_ENV=test
Schema migrations table does not exist yet.
rwc $ rake test
Run options: --seed 43484

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.011646s, 85.8671 runs/s, 85.8671 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The test is not interacting with the database, still I expected there to be an error due to migrations that have not been applied.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Literally just read the following:

> In order to run your tests, your test database will need to have the
>   current structure. The test helper checks whether your test database
>   has any pending migrations. If so, it will try to load your
>   db/schema.rb or db/structure.sql into the test database. If migrations
>   are still pending, an error will be raised. Usually this indicates
>   that your schema is not fully migrated. Running the migrations against
>   the development database (bin/rake db:migrate) will bring the schema
>   up to date.

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-sets-up-for-testing-from-the-word-go